# Getting a memory overflow?

Tags: c, sockets, fwrite, fread, file-descriptor

Im not quite sure why. But im getting a memory overflow in my file sent over a network connection.

I use send.txt as a test file with a few million digits of pi to send from client to server, and it works great the first time. The file copies with no errors, but if I try to send the same file again it will rewrite the file exactly as before but with a memory overflow?
p <-- These are the two characters that are overwritten to the end. Different sized text files add a different number of char's overflowed, but its not consistent.

I should mention that the server side is multi-threaded to allow more than one connection at once if that matters. I dont think it would but I thought that would be relevant information.

Server

```
    void write_file(int sockfd)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char fileName[100] = {0};
        char fileLenStr[100] = {0};
        int fileLen;
        char byte[1] = {0};
        char *buffer;
        while (1) 
        {
            read(sockfd,byte,1);
            if (byte[0] == 32) 
            {
                break;
            }
            size_t len = strlen(fileName);
            printf("%s\n",fileName);
            if (len == 0) 
            {
                fileName[0] = byte[0];
            } 
            else 
            {
                fileName[len++] = byte[0];
                len = strlen(fileName);
                fileName[len++] = '\0';
            }
        }
        while (1) 
        {
            size_t len;
            read(sockfd,byte,1);
            if (byte[0] == 32) 
            {
                len = strlen(fileLenStr);
                break;
            }
            len = strlen(fileLenStr);
            printf("%ld\n",len);
            if (len == 0) 
            {
                fileLenStr[0] = byte[0];
            } 
            else 
            {
                fileLenStr[len++] = byte[0];
                len = strlen(fileLenStr);
                fileLenStr[len++] = '\0';
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n",fileName);
        fileLen = atoi(fileLenStr);
        buffer = (char *)malloc(fileLen * sizeof(char));
        read(sockfd,buffer,(fileLen * sizeof(char)));
        fp = fopen(fileName, "w");
        fwrite(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), fp);
        fclose(fp);
        free(buffer);
        return;
    }
```

Client

```
    void pushFile(char *fileName, int clientSocket)
    {
        char cmd[60] = {0};
        char *data;
        char response[4];
        FILE *fp;
        struct stat stats;
        int intfileSizeinBytes;
        char fileSizeinBytes[10];
        int st = stat(fileName,&stats);
        if(st == -1)
        {
            printf("Error in stat method...\n");
        } 
        else 
        {
            intfileSizeinBytes = (int)stats.st_size;
            sprintf(fileSizeinBytes,"%d",intfileSizeinBytes);
        }
        fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("File can't be opened...\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        data = (char *)malloc(intfileSizeinBytes * sizeof(char));
        fread(data, intfileSizeinBytes, 1, fp);
        //remove(fileName);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("FILENAME: %s\n", fileName);
        sprintf(cmd, "PUSH %s %d ", fileName, intfileSizeinBytes);
        int w = send(clientSocket, cmd, strlen(cmd),0);
        
        w = send(clientSocket, data, strlen(data), 0);
        free(data);
        return;

}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `strlen` on `data` you should allocate an extra byte and 0 terminate it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry where are you referring to? Thats why I do fileLenStr[len++] = '\0';

Comment: @AlexanderCrowe Here `data = (char *)malloc(intfileSizeinBytes * sizeof(char));`. The last character is probably the newline character that you read in. Replace that with `\0` Also I don't see `cmd` ending with a `\0`

Comment: Every use of `strlen()` in this code is wrong, and needs to be either removed or rewritten. The data is not being null terminated properly, and most of the `strlen()`s can be replaced by simply initializing the `len` variable to 0 and then incrementing it. Worse, there is no error handling on any of the `read()` or `send()` calls. And this code will fail badly if the `fileName` has space characters in it. You should delimit the `fileNmae` better, or else send the `fileName`'s length before sending the `fileName` itself, just as you send the file's size before sending the file's data.